# Find Previous Prime Number using R

Tags: r

I am trying to find Previous Prime number of given value. The mentioned code works fine if I pass prime Number straight away as input **lp(7) returns 7**. But if I pass **lp(6)** none are displaying. I am expecting **5** to return.
How do I find the previous prime Number for given one.

Suggestions / Corrections are much appreciated

```
lp <- function(x){
     
     temp <- x:2
     
     while (x == 2L || all(x %% 2L:max(2,floor(sqrt(x))) != 0))
         
     {
         return(x)
     }
     
     
 }
```

Comment: Maybe this doesn't belong here, it seems more of a math type of question

Comment: You don't use temp and your while loop executes exactly one time. What do you think your while-loop does?

Comment: Do you mean for your code to iterate? You create `temp`, but never use it again. `x` never changes, it's always the input. You need to think/talk through the logic of how your code is supposed to work.

Comment: Most while loops that iterate might start with `i <- 1` before the loop, and then have `i <- i + 1` inside the loop, and perhaps have the `return(x)` after the loop (or maybe `return(temp[i])`, hint hint).

Comment: I was using trial and Error on all scenarios. You can ignore temp which is of no use. Yes i expect it to iterate. But unable to crack the missing piece

Answer (score 1):

If you run this function a lot of times, probably most efficient is to generate a list of primes once, and search where your value lies in that sequence

```
library(primes)
primes = generate_primes(2, 1e6)
find_lower_prime = function(x) {
  primes[findInterval(x, primes)]
}

find_lower_prime(6)
# [1] 5
```

Comment: Forgot to mention . I cant use prime library. Few libraries are not allowed. Agenda is to create a function on own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
lp <- function(x){
  
  previousNumbers <- 2:x
  
  previousPrimes <- sapply(previousNumbers, function(num) {
    divisorsToCheck <- 2:max(2,floor(sqrt(num)))
    if(num == 2 | all(num %% divisorsToCheck != 0)) {
      return(num)
    } else {
      return(NA)
    }
  })
  
  previousPrimes[!is.na(previousPrimes)]
}
```

to get all previous primes.

```
lp(18) # 2  3  5  7 11 13 17
lp(5) #2 3 5
```

Comment: Thanks. But I do have prime sequence using sieve model. But I am expecting immediate prime in reverse order

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code lie below

```
lp <- function(x) {
  p <- x - 1
  repeat {
    if (p %in% c(2, 3) | all(p %% ceiling(sqrt(2:p)) != 0)) {
      return(p)
    }
    p <- p - 1
  }
}
```

and you will see

```
> lp(5)
[1] 3

> lp(6)
[1] 5

> lp(7)
[1] 5

> lp(8)
[1] 7

> lp(11)
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi All this worked for me ..

```
lp <- function(x){
   
for(i in x:2)

{  
     while (i == 2L || all(i %% 2L:max(2,floor(sqrt(i))) != 0))
       
     {
         return(i)       
         
     }
     
}
     
 }
```