# R next prime number Inclusive of start

Tags: r

I have the below existing code in R. The code prints the next immediate prime number. I want to consider inclusive of starting number

```
np <- function(x){
 if (x==1L | x==2L) {return(2L)}
 else { 
  temp <- x+1
  test <- 2:x
  while( any( (temp %% test) == 0 ) ){
    temp <- temp+1
  }
  temp
} }
```

Eg.. np(7) returns 11. But expected output is 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below (following a similar idea in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824599/12158757))

```
np <- function(x) {
  p <- x
  repeat {
    if (p %in% c(2, 3) | all(p %% ceiling(sqrt(2:p)) != 0)) {
      return(p)
    }
    p <- p + 1
  }
}
```

and you will see

```
> np(2)
[1] 2

> np(3)
[1] 3

> np(4)
[1] 5

> np(5)
[1] 5

> np(7)
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's stupid but does this do the trip?

```
np <- function(x){
  if (x==1L | x==2L) {return(2L)}
  else { 
    x= x-1
    temp <- x+1
    test <- 2:x
    while( any( (temp %% test) == 0 ) ){
      temp <- temp+1
    }
    temp
  } }
```

Comment: elielink My saviour _/\_

Answer (score 1):

You are testing numbers above `x` only by calling `temp <- x+1`. Here is a version that should work with minimal changes to your code:

```
np <- function(x){
 if (x==1L | x==2L) {return(2L)}
 else { 
  temp <- x
  test <- 2:(x - 1)
  while( any( (temp %% test) == 0 ) ){
    temp <- temp+1
  }
  temp
} }
```

Comment: Yes it is minimal. Thanks ktiu